# mock private constructor using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a singleton class with private constructor and want to write unit tests for that.

Any idea how to mock a class which has private constructor using mockito framework.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this answer points into the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138153/how-does-mockito-create-an-instance-of-the-mock-object

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write tests for the singleton class, or tests for classes that use the singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should be able to use this library: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/ to do it. But it is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst not answering your question directly, I think it would be worth reading about the [singleton anti-pattern](http://caines.ca/blog/programming/singletons-anti-pattern-or-worst-anti-pattern-ever/), and perhaps consider an alternative approach such as [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) with which to compose your application.