# Mockito verify constructor calls method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to test when the `Game` class is instantiated, that the `start` method is called. However I get the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
game.start();
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I have the following class called `Game`

```
public class Game {
    private Hand player_hand;
    private Hand dealer_hand;
    public static Boolean isInPlay;

    public Game() {
        player_hand = new Hand();
        dealer_hand = new Hand();
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        isInPlay = true;
        player_hand.hit();
        player_hand.hit();
        System.out.println("Player hand: ");
        player_hand.printHands();
        instantWinLose();
        dealer_hand.hit();
        dealer_hand.hit();
    }
}
```

I have a test class called `GameTest`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)

public class GameTest {

@InjectMocks
Game game;

@Mock
Hand hand;

    @Test
    public void testGameConstruction() {
        Game mockedGame = mock(Game.class);
        verify(mockedGame, times(1)).start();
    }
}
```

I'm new to Mockito. I've tried following examples in [Difference between @Mock and @InjectMocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467685/difference-between-mock-and-injectmocks) but I still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Mockito.mock(SomeType.class)`, Mockito will dynamically create a subclass for that type but for instantiation it uses certain techniques to avoid calling the super constructor ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138153/how-does-mockito-create-an-instance-of-the-mock-object)).

Try this:

```
public class Foobar {

    public Foobar () {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}

// Somewhere else ...
Mockito.mock(Foobar.class); // No exception will be thrown because constructor is never called
```

That makes sense, when you think about it: A fresh mock object should not be doing anything unless it is absolutely required (stubbing). Calling any real logic could have undesired side effects.

And that is why you never mock the class under test itself!

**When you mock the class under test itself, your tests have absolutely no meaning at all!**

Only mock dependencies.

Your `Game` class has no dependencies, so you won't be needing any mocks:

```
    @Test
    public void testGameConstruction() {
        Game game = new Game();
        assertTrue(game.isInGame());
    }
```

If `Game` had dependencies, for instance `Hand`, you could add constructor parameters:

```
public Game (Hand hand1, Hand hand2) { .... }
```

and then:

```
    @Test
    public void testGameConstruction() {

        Hand handMock1 = Mockito.mock(Hand.class);
        Hand handMock2 = Mockito.mock(Hand.class);
        Game game = new Game(handMock1, handMock2);

        verify(handMock1, times(1)).hit();
        verify(handMock2, times(1)).hit();

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't my `Game` class _currently_ have a dependency on `Hand` anyway? [dependencies](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html).

Comment: I'm sorry. I was looking for a simple term and didn't want to confuse you. You are right. From an OO-perspective `Game`depends on `Hand` but in order to _test_ `Game` you don't need to know anything about `Hand` since `Game` handles everything internally and provides a no-arg constructor. From a testing perspective, you most of the time want to ignore _how_ something works. You want to make sure it works!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, You need to call the start method then only your mocking will be validated with times.

something like ::
  mockedGames.start()

Then only it call will be verified

Answer (score 0):

How I understand, by mocking Game class you also mocking constructor. That's mean that no code from actual class constructer was run. Try to create an instance of Game class without mocking.