# How exactly is Mockito able to instantiate classes without calling their constructors?

Tags: java, mockito

How is Mockito able to instantiate classes without calling their constructors? This test passes:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class MockitoWondersTest {
    @Test
    void testInstantiationWithoutConstructorInvocation() {
        NonInstantiableClass nonInstantiableClassMock = mock(NonInstantiableClass.class);
    }

    private static class NonInstantiableClass {
        public NonInstantiableClass() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't instantiate NonInstantiableClass!");
        }
    }
}
```

It's certainly not a runtime proxy thing (besides the fact that super-constructors would still be invoked, I checked what `getClass()` returns)

Does it tinker with bytecode? It seems so. I noticed in the debugger my class has a `toString()` that I didn't write (something along the lines of "MyClass mock, hascode 123456"). Does it add a no-args to my class's bytecode and invoke it?

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138153/how-does-mockito-create-an-instance-of-the-mock-object), but it's still not clear to me

> Mockito is using reflection and CGLib to extend the [target class] with a dynamically created superclass. As part of this, it starts by making all the constructors of [target class] public - including the default constructor, which is still around but private if you declared a constructor which takes parameters.
>
> I presume that it calls the default constructor when the superclass is created, though I haven't tested that.

Does it mean that Mockito manipulates the bytecode of `NonInstantiableClass` so that it extends `SomeMockitoSuperclass`? How does it help exactly? My throwing constructor is still there. It's impossible to instantiate the class without invoking it. Does Mockito modify the bytecode of that constructor? Or does it actually instantiate `SomeMockitoSuperclass`? Then why does `mock.getClass()` return `com.example.NonInstantiableClass` instead of `com.example.SomeMockitoSuperclass`?

Another asnwer has a different explanation

> Mockito uses CGLib to generate class object. However to instantiate this class object it uses Objenesis http://objenesis.org/tutorial.html
>
> Objenesis is able to instantiate object without constructor using various techniques (i.e. calling ObjectStream.readObject and similar).

In my case, it seems Objenesis is not utilized. I ran it with the debugger and this doesn't throw (from `org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker`)

```java
                try {
                    // We attempt to use the "native" mock maker first that avoids
                    // Objenesis and Unsafe
                    instance = newInstance(type);
                } catch (InstantiationException ignored) {
```

I debugged it further, got to the line `DISPATCHER.invokeWithArguments` (from `org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.InstrumentationMemberAccessor.newInstance(..)`), pressed `Step Into` and that's it. It never jumped anywhere from there

```java
            Object value =
                    onConstruction.invoke(
                            () -> {
                                try {
                                    // Use handle.asFixedArity() to handle varargs bindings properly
                                    // (as by default Java will create method handle with
                                    // asVarargsCollector), fe:
                                    //
                                    //   private static class Varargs {
                                    //     Varargs(String whatever, Observer... observers) {
                                    //     }
                                    //   }
                                    return DISPATCHER.invokeWithArguments(
                                            handle.asFixedArity(), arguments);
                                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                                    thrown.set(true);
                                    return throwable;
                                }
                            });
```

It might have to do with the fact that `DISPATCHER` is of type `org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.InstrumentationMemberAccessor.Dispatcher`, an interface, that doesn't have any compile-time implementations. Here's how that dispatcher is initialized. Notice it intercepts "invokeWithArguments" calls. However, what it does next, after intercepting that call, is not clear to me

```java
            dispatcher =
                    new ByteBuddy()
                            .subclass(Dispatcher.class)
                            .method(named("getLookup"))
                            .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(MethodHandles.class.getMethod("lookup")))
                            .method(named("getModule"))
                            .intercept(
                                    MethodCall.invoke(Class.class.getMethod("getModule"))
                                            .onMethodCall(
                                                    MethodCall.invoke(
                                                            Object.class.getMethod("getClass"))))
                            .method(named("setAccessible"))
                            .intercept(
                                    MethodCall.invoke(
                                                    AccessibleObject.class.getMethod(
                                                            "setAccessible", boolean.class))
                                            .onArgument(0)
                                            .withArgument(1))
                            .method(named("invokeWithArguments"))
                            .intercept(
                                    MethodCall.invoke(
                                                    MethodHandle.class.getMethod(
                                                            "invokeWithArguments", Object[].class))
                                            .onArgument(0)
                                            .withArgument(1))
                            .make()
                            .load(
                                    InstrumentationMemberAccessor.class.getClassLoader(),
                                    ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                            .getLoaded()
                            .getConstructor()
                            .newInstance();
```

Judging from the method names (`.onArgument(0).withArgument(1)`), I guess that dispatcher then invokes `invokeWithArguments()` on `DirectMethodHandle.Constructor` (that's what `handle.asFixedArity()` returns) which is a subtype of `MethodHandle`. Here's the `invokeWithArguments()` method that is defined in that class

```java
    public Object invokeWithArguments(Object... arguments) throws Throwable {
        // Note: Jumbo argument lists are handled in the variable-arity subclass.
        MethodType invocationType = MethodType.genericMethodType(arguments == null ? 0 : arguments.length);
        return invocationType.invokers().spreadInvoker(0).invokeExact(asType(invocationType), arguments);
    }
```

Notice `invokeExact()`. It belongs to the same `MethodHandle` class and is native. So there's seemingly no way of figuring out what happens next

```java
    @IntrinsicCandidate
    public final native @PolymorphicSignature Object invokeExact(Object... args) throws Throwable;
```

But ok, let's just assume it somehow natively executes *something* (something that is encapsulated by the first argument passed to invokeExact(), a `MethodHandle`). What is that something? Does the `MethodHandle` store some sort of reference to my constructor (directly or not)? What code is invoked when *actually creating* the instance at the end of the day?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does mockito create an instance of the mock object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138153/how-does-mockito-create-an-instance-of-the-mock-object)

Comment: @JuanCNuno I read it but still don't quite understand

Comment: Mockito manipulates the byte code. In other words: it uses a scientific form of Black Magic, invalidating all the good things java was designed for.

Comment: Originaly java was designed and *documented* in a strictness never seen before, making C++ look like trash. It enables IDEs like eclipse to unambiguously  analyze the code, to find all places where a variable value is used or set. Reflection was *The Original Sin*, breaking the concept, subtlety. Manipulation of byte code is even more brute. The result: you can't relay on anything.

Answer (score -1):

Mockito achieves this by utilizing dynamic proxy objects or bytecode manipulation libraries (such as CGLIB) to create a proxy instance of the class.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: In Java, you can create proxy instances of interfaces using the java.lang.reflect.Proxy class. Mockito often uses dynamic proxies to create mock objects when the mocked class is an interface. Dynamic proxies allow the creation of objects at runtime that implement a given set of interfaces

Comment: My class doesn't implement any interfaces

Comment: @Hepoha Given the user's other answer today, this one is likely just a copy/paste from ChatGPT as well.